# How to draw minimum ellipse that encloses the text of various lengths

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, calculation, ellipse

Please see diagram below.

And please explain it in terms of coordinates of the shaded rectangles.
If I have the coordinates of shaded rectangles, center_x and center_y of the whole group, how can I find the ellipse's xradius and yradius to draw the ellipse shown last?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is probably a minimum-volume ellipsoid over a set. Your set is determined by the text boxes, which themselves are completely determined by the 4 vertices of each box. Your ellipse centered at x1 can be determined by a center vector mu and sym pos.def shape matrix A as

Ell(mu,A) = {x  such that (x-mu)'*A*(x-mu)<=1}
So the minimum volume problem can be shown to be

```
min -log(Det(A)) 
s.t. (v_i-mu)'*A*(v_i-mu)<=1 }
```

where (v_i[0],v_i[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CElkP.png)) are the plane coordinates of your points (the corners of your boxes).
There is a way of embedding this in a higher dimension to get rid of the mu's

```
min -log(Det(B)) 
s.t. ([v_i,1])'*B*(v_i-mu)<=1 }
```

And this is a convex problem, there are multiple algorithms to solve it, here is one based on the ellipsoid method:[image]

Comment: Sorry I don't understand can you elaborate in layman's terms?
I don't know how to do matrix math, can i get away with for loops and if checks?

Comment: Well, if your text is always lined up nice and symmetric, so that the optimal ellipse has its axes alligned with xy axis, you can formulate the problem as min (pi*a*b) s.t. (v_i[0]-mu_0)^2/a^2 +(v_i[1]_-mu_0)^2/a^2 <=1 for all text corners v_i. You control a,b, mu_0, and mu_1.  This is no longer convex, but you might still converge with a primal-dual approach.

Comment: Thanks for answering. it gave me clue as to how solving my problem. I think i did it answered my own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the ideal solution. But it seems to work for me.
Since my text is always aligned centered.

1. I start with an ellipse shape that fits inside the rectangle drawn in figure 2 in question.(made of xradius and yradius = half width and half height of rectangle).
2. I loop through the text boxes and for each text box (a) find a corner
   used this formula found here
   [radius length of ellipse at any angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432902/how-to-get-the-radius-of-an-ellipse-at-a-specific-angle-by-knowing-its-semi-majo) where a and b are just my half width and half height of my large rectangle and center is just center of current ellipse and theta is angle from center to the corner of text box. I call this ellipseRadius. then (b) I find the length from center to the corner call it hyp (short for Hypotenuse) (c) Divide hyp by ellipseRadius to get a factor. This is the factor (call it factor) that I must multiply my xradius and yradius by to include that corner keeping the same aspect ratio of the shape i started with. But I don't multiply it yet.
   (d)I just keep looping and looking for a maximum factor (call it maxFactor).
3. When I am done the loop I set my xradius = xradius * maxFactor and yradius = yradius * maxFactor
4. Draw ellipse with newly set xradius and yradius from step 3.
   That's it.

Here's example of what it produces (in black labels compared to previous light green labels):
As you can see the black labels surround the text but with no too much space like the green labels do. This is what I wanted to achieve.

[image]